# VS2013 - nuget.org gallery not showing

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget, nuget-package, nugetgallery

Trying to get the nugget.org gallery to show in VS2013 with no success.

Have installed the latest Nuget Package Manager extension is installed and ensure that the package source is pointing to nuget.org

[image]

I just can't seem to get the nuget.org gallery to appear.  On either machines with VS2013 Update 4 installed.

Any idea or help to get this working.

Comment: If you go into options.  Package Manager-->Package Sources.  Is NuGet official checked?

Comment: It does appear to be

Comment: All I can think of is to remove nuget and reinstall

Comment: are you talking about the package manager - as this didn't help.

Comment: yeah.  so you removed it in Extensions and Updates?  Behind a corporate firewall that blocks it or anything?  Would still be listed, but unaccessible I would think.  Hmmm.....

Comment: What's listed in your Updates(7)?

Comment: Product updates but absolutely nothing to do with nuget

Answer (score 0):

The window in your screenshot is the Visual Studio Extension Manager. To access the Nuget repository you first need to create or open a project and then right-click the references item in the project (in the solution explorer). from the context menu you should find the option to "manage nuget packages for project". That will open the NuGet Repository screen.